# difference between /etc/map/testmap and /etc/map/testmap.internal

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem

whats the difference between /etc/map/testmap and /etc/map/testmap.internal.

under system/console/jcrresolver at the bottom of the page, it says:

Mapping Map Entries(/etc/map/testmap.internal)
"Lists the entries used by the ResourceResolver.map methods to map Resource Paths to URLs , How is it used and is related with normal map.

Answer (score 0):

These maps do not belong to a vanity AEM instance. In a clean AEM instance you have just one single map placed under /etc/map. The map definitions are used by the resource resolver to map URIs to resources and vice versa.